# Getting original object state after a method call which modifies the object

Tags: java

I started studying OOP concepts in Java and I was trying to create a basic class for points, lines, planes and surfaces but I'm having trouble with a method I created.

```
public class Punto{
  public double x, y;

  public Punto(double pX, double pY){
      this.x = pX;
      this.y = pY;
  }

  public String puntoTela(){
      return "( " + x + " , " + y + " )";
  }

  public void rotacion(double grado) {
      double rad = (grado * Math.PI) / 180;

      this.x = (this.x * Math.cos(rad) + this.y * - Math.sin(rad));
      this.y = (this.x * Math.sin(rad) + this.y * Math.cos(rad));       
  }


 }
```

My problem is: if i declare `Punto p = new Punto(5, 2)` and call the `rotation` method i can't go back to the original value.

```
public class Ejemplo {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Punto p = new Punto(5, 2);
       System.out.println(p.puntoTela()); // shows (5, 2)

        p.rotacion(45);
        System.out.println(p.puntoTela()); // shows (5, 2) after rotatin 90 deg = (2.1, 2.9)

        System.out.println(p.x); // 2.1 i want original value of 5


    }

}
```

I tried to create local variables for the rotation method but it isn't working What should I do?? Gracias!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Your `rotacion` method modifies the object. Do you want to create a copy of the object? Or have your method return something?

Comment: you are using p.y in the p.x calculation without updating p.y and then usig the updated p.x on the p.y

Comment: Rotate the object by -45 degrees?

Answer (score 5):

You can make the `Punto` class [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). The `rotation` method (and other "mutator" methods) would then return a new (modified) object instead of changing the original one:

```
public Punto rotacion(double grado) {
      double rad = (grado * Math.PI) / 180;

      double newX = (this.x * Math.cos(rad) + this.y * - Math.sin(rad));
      double newY = (this.x * Math.sin(rad) + this.y * Math.cos(rad));       

      return new Punto(newX, newY);
  }
```

You can observe this pattern in many JDK classes, such as `BigDecimal`, `LocalDate`, `String`, etc.

The usage is then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Punto p = new Punto(5, 2);
    System.out.println(p.puntoTela()); // shows (5, 2)

    // Note that the new value is assigned to a new variable, 
    // so that we still have access to the old value
    Punto rotated = p.rotacion(45);
    System.out.println(rotated.puntoTela()); // rotated

    System.out.println(p.x); // original
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

- create a method `void rotate(double grado)` that changes the object itself
- create a method `Punto rotated(double grado)` which returns a new `Point` that is equivalent to the original point rotated by some amount

What you cannot do is have one object be rotated and not rotated at the same time.